# Posicionamento CSS no _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou tendo problemas de posicionamento com o `@RenderBody()`, não estou conseguindo ajustar conforme o menu lateral, gostaria de uma solução, obrigado.

[image: Imagem]

```
<div class="nav-side-menu">
    <div class="brand">Life Players</div>
    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></i>

    <div class="menu-list">

        <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-lg"></i> Dashboard
                </a>
            </li>

            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#products" class="collapsed active">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i> UI Elements <span class="arrow"></span></a>
            </li>
            <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="products">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">CSS3 Animation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">General</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Buttons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tabs & Accordions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Typography</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FontAwesome</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Slider</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Panels</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Widgets</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bootstrap Model</a></li>
            </ul>


            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#service" class="collapsed">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe fa-lg"></i> Services <span class="arrow"></span></a>
            </li>
            <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="service">
                <li>New Service 1</li>
                <li>New Service 2</li>
                <li>New Service 3</li>
            </ul>


            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#new" class="collapsed">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-car fa-lg"></i> New <span class="arrow"></span></a>
            </li>
            <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="new">
                <li>New New 1</li>
                <li>New New 2</li>
                <li>New New 3</li>
            </ul>


            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i> Profile
                </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-users fa-lg"></i> Users
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
</div>
```

O @RenderBody() é como se fosse um php include, ele da um include de outro arquivo que no caso é a tabela que aparece na imagem.

(Código da Tabela)

```
@{
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<table style="width: 100%;" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="left">

    <thead>
        <tr role="row">
            <th aria-label="Tipo de Destino" style="width: 20%;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" tabindex="0" role="columnheader" class="sorting" width="20%">Player ID</th>
            <th aria-label="Tipo de Destino" style="width: 20%;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" tabindex="0" role="columnheader" class="sorting" width="20%">Name</th>
            <th aria-label="Tipo de Destino" style="width: 20%;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" tabindex="0" role="columnheader" class="sorting" width="20%">Aliases</th>
            <th aria-label="Tipo de Destino" style="width: 10%;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" tabindex="0" role="columnheader" class="sorting" width="10%">Arrested</th>
            <th aria-label="Tipo de Destino" style="width: 10%;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" tabindex="0" role="columnheader" class="sorting" width="10%">Jail Time</th>
            <th aria-label="Tipo de Destino" style="width: 10%;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" tabindex="0" role="columnheader" class="sorting" width="10%">Cop Level</th>
            <th aria-label="Tipo de Destino" style="width: 10%;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" tabindex="0" role="columnheader" class="sorting" width="10%">Medic Level</th>            
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody aria-relevant="all" aria-live="polite" role="alert">
            <tr class="odd">
                <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
                <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                <td class=" ">No</td>
                <td class=" ">0</td>
                <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                <td class=" ">Civil</td>
            </tr>

        <tr class="odd">
            <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">No</td>
            <td class=" ">0</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="odd">
            <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">No</td>
            <td class=" ">0</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="odd">
            <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">No</td>
            <td class=" ">0</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="odd">
            <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">No</td>
            <td class=" ">0</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="odd">
            <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">No</td>
            <td class=" ">0</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="odd">
            <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">No</td>
            <td class=" ">0</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="odd">
            <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">No</td>
            <td class=" ">0</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="odd">
            <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">No</td>
            <td class=" ">0</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="odd">
            <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">No</td>
            <td class=" ">0</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="odd">
            <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">No</td>
            <td class=" ">0</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="odd">
            <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">No</td>
            <td class=" ">0</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="odd">
            <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">No</td>
            <td class=" ">0</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="odd">
            <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">No</td>
            <td class=" ">0</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="odd">
            <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
            <td class=" ">No</td>
            <td class=" ">0</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
            <td class=" ">Civil</td>
        </tr>


    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: OBS: Estou utilizando bootstrap

Comment: Poderia postar o código do layout e explicar melhor que posicionamento é esse?

Comment: Aproveitando, Bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Percebi que está começando agora no SOpt. Leia o guia [ask] e o faça um [tour], para aprender um pouco mais sobre o funcionamento do site para assim aumentar suas chances de conseguir uma boa resposta.

Comment: O posicionamento que eu falo seria do @RenderBody() dentro do _Layout.cshtml para se ajustar conforme o menu lateral (como mostra na imagem)

Comment: Mas o seu código não está como a imagem hoje? Ainda não consegui entender o que você quer.

Comment: De uma olhada, a tabela está por trás do menu lateral, eu quero que a tabela se ajuste ao lado do menu lateral

Comment: Entendi. bom, se está usando bootstrap, tente utilziar o sistema de grids que não está. Tipo: menu: `<div class="col-md-2">menu aqui</menu>` e tabela: `<div class="col-md-2">RenderBody() Aquii</menu>`. Qualquer coisa daqui a pouco formulo uma resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ao que eu saiba](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/), para funcionar, a `<table>` precisa estar pelo menos dentro de uma `<div class="row">` e depois dentro de uma `<div>` que configure a responsividade. Por exemplo:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table style="width: 100%;" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="left">

            <thead>
                <tr role="row">
                    <th aria-label="Tipo de Destino" style="width: 20%;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" tabindex="0" role="columnheader" class="sorting" width="20%">Player ID</th>
                    <th aria-label="Tipo de Destino" style="width: 20%;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" tabindex="0" role="columnheader" class="sorting" width="20%">Name</th>
                    <th aria-label="Tipo de Destino" style="width: 20%;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" tabindex="0" role="columnheader" class="sorting" width="20%">Aliases</th>
                    <th aria-label="Tipo de Destino" style="width: 10%;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" tabindex="0" role="columnheader" class="sorting" width="10%">Arrested</th>
                    <th aria-label="Tipo de Destino" style="width: 10%;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" tabindex="0" role="columnheader" class="sorting" width="10%">Jail Time</th>
                    <th aria-label="Tipo de Destino" style="width: 10%;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" tabindex="0" role="columnheader" class="sorting" width="10%">Cop Level</th>
                    <th aria-label="Tipo de Destino" style="width: 10%;" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" tabindex="0" role="columnheader" class="sorting" width="10%">Medic Level</th>            
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody aria-relevant="all" aria-live="polite" role="alert">
                    <tr class="odd">
                        <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
                        <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                        <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                        <td class=" ">No</td>
                        <td class=" ">0</td>
                        <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                        <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                    </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">No</td>
                    <td class=" ">0</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">No</td>
                    <td class=" ">0</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">No</td>
                    <td class=" ">0</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">No</td>
                    <td class=" ">0</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">No</td>
                    <td class=" ">0</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">No</td>
                    <td class=" ">0</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">No</td>
                    <td class=" ">0</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">No</td>
                    <td class=" ">0</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">No</td>
                    <td class=" ">0</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">No</td>
                    <td class=" ">0</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">No</td>
                    <td class=" ">0</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">No</td>
                    <td class=" ">0</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">No</td>
                    <td class=" ">0</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class=" ">76561198063412200</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">Pioneer</td>
                    <td class=" ">No</td>
                    <td class=" ">0</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                    <td class=" ">Civil</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, consegui conforme o que você e o Randrade disseram mas tive de fazer algumas alterações. <div class="row" style="padding-left: 320px;">
        <div class="col-md-11">
            @RenderBody()
            <hr />
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: Possivelmente. Só não recomendo colocar `<div class="row">` antes de `@RenderBody` que não fica bom.

Comment: <div class="col-md-11" style="padding-left: 340px;">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
    </div>

E coloquei o a div class "row" dentro do .cshtml onde se encontra somente a Table

Comment: Segue print, http://puu.sh/moizr/3fdb26a09a.png

Comment: Agora sim. Dá pra usar `col-md-12` ao invés de `col-md-11` pra preencher todo o espaço da tela.

Comment: Deu certinho com o col-md-12, muito obrigado!